# How to restrict app download only from the iPhone 6S and above devices in Apple's App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, appstore-approval

The game app uses so much RAM up to 1GB

Comment: I think that the only way to restrict downloads is via `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` and there is no key that would restrict anything from a iPhone5s  or greater. see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1

Comment: HealthKit is available only 5s onwards , even i restrict with this , Is it make any problem?

Comment: I suspect that apple would not look kindly on adding required device capabilities that have nothing to do with your app, also HealthKit is available from iPhone 4s onwards.  I would suggest limiting based on `arm64` which would limit anything below iPhone 5s,   but that still wouldn't help you if your limiting factor is RAM; iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ only have 1 GB or ram.

Comment: @JonRose If I create an app for the iPhone non-universal. It's still downloadable for the iPod touch or the iPad?

Comment: Have you considered tuning your game so that it's not such a memory hog?

Comment: the deployment device target does not restrict download.  An iPod touch and an iPad can download iPhone apps.  As far as I know only `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` can restrict download based on device.

Comment: Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html. Here arm64 can be used as UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, as it is available from iPhone 5S which has 1gb ram.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: The question is old; nevertheless, based on [Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1) guideline by Apple, "arkit" could be your best shot.<br>
N.B. It lets "iPhone SE" through, but based on your RAM requirements, it should be fine, since it has 2GBs.